# navbar list creating a box around it

Tags: html, css

I am building a website that has multiple languages in Albanian language I have an issue, I have "Home" "Contact" "About" and a language selector on the navbar. When I switch to Albanian that translated to: "Ballina" "Kontakt and "Rreth Nesh" when in Albanian there is a box created around these in white color how can I remove that? I tried to change the font but when I do that this time the box appears on the English version. It's like a loop, Also this only happens on mobile view it works fine on desktop.

```css
li,
a,
button {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #edf0f1;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <img class="logo" src="../images/selcon-logo.png" alt="logo">
  <nav>
    <center>
      <ul class="nav-links">
        <li class="li-al"><a class="home-li" href="home-al.html">Ballina</a></li>
        <li class="li-al"><a class="contact-li" href="contact-al.html">Kontakt</a></li>
        <li class="li-al"><a class="about-li" href="about-al.html">Rreth Nesh</a></li>
        <li>
          <select id="language-selector">
            <option value="en">EN</option>
            <option value="mk">MK</option>
            <option value="al">AL</option>
          </select>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </center>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Side note, don't use `<center>`. It's been obsolete for years

Comment: How are the elements translated, e.g. are you using a library? Do you experience the same behaviour in the mobile view of the debugger? What causes the boxes to appear, i.e. can you inspect what the boxes are? With the code provided we are unable to observe your described issue.

Comment: only thing that affects it is the font-size

Comment: Also when I zoom in on the line's they disappear.